# Is Jasmine advise to reduce local variable or karma coverage report?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-coverage

My Karma coverage report shows to cover the local variable. is that possible or its a `karma-coverage` report issue.

Please have a look at the Angular Controller Code.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('moduleName')
    .controller('FormController', [ '$log',
        function FormController($log) {

            // Controller Local Variables.
            var that = this;

            that.hideLoader = function () {
                that.isLoading = false;
            };

        }
]);
```

[image]

> My Question: Is that possible to cover the local variables and function parameter conditions. for instance is below.

```
that.hideLoader = function (userObj) {
   var id = userObj.id;

   if(id) {
     that.isLoading = false;
   }
   else {
     that.isError = true;
   }
};
```

In the above example, I have declared user object id attribute to local `id` variable. now its very tough to cover the code. in this case, jasmine advise to reduce local variable or its karma-coverage report suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

> my karma coverage report wants to cover the local variable. is that
>   possible or its a karma-coverage report issue.

The coverage tool is working correctly by checking that your tests cover every line of code. That is the definition of code coverage.

On the other hand:

```
var that = this;
that.hideLoader = function() { that.isLoading = false};
```

are **NOT** local variables. As defined, they are properties of your controller. Word of caution: please use `"use strict"` and don't use undeclared properties such as `that.isLoading`. It is not very readable and it is bad practice even though the language allows for it.

Also, when asking questions please paste the code and not images of the code.

**Update**

The answer to your question is yes. Karma-coverage reports on every line of code touched (green), or untouched (red).

Comment: may be you misunderstood the question. my question is about that variable and my question has the code what you are looking for !!

Comment: I have updated the question in detail including title with code examples

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I did misunderstand. I've also updated the answer. Cheers